# How to stop USB Audio Interface distorting sound in Ubuntu?

Tags: audio-interfaces, interference

I have very simple USB interface (Line 6 Tone Port UX1), and I would like to use it's microphone and instrument plugs, to record some things in Ubuntu.
The interface works very well in windows. In ubuntu I can monitor sound through the interface, but when I plug in the microphone and speak, it sounds distorted. This is indepedent from the program I use to record (Ardour). So, when I try to record, the distorted sound is present.
 I don't have a clue about why this happens, and I have not been able to fix it. Any idea? 
As for the instrument entrance, i don't think it is being detected in the computer, or I don't know how to activate it so that it works.

Comment: Line 6 gear usually requires dedicated drivers - I don't think they make nix drivers, the web site shows only Mac & Win. http://uk.line6.com/software/

Comment: Line 6 has had Linux drivers for years. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/sound/usb/line6